# Convert Bootstrap @media only screen to Foundation?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, zurb-foundation-6

Zurb Foundation crashes with Bootstraps on screen sizes, eg:

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 320px) {
    .button-home {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
}
```

This code won't work when Zurb Foundation is included.

How can avoid/ fix this?

Or better how do I convert that code to Foundation?

I need Bootstrap and Foundation to be present on my site at the moment.

**Notes:**

- The red colour **should present only** on smaller screens. now it is present on all screen sizes.
- I have Foundation loaded **after** Bootstrap.
- I am on "bootstrap": "^3.3.7", "foundation-sites": "^6.3.0-rc1"

Comment: When I apply foundation and bootstrap, a `button.button-home` has a red border and a margin. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: the red colour **should present only** on smaller screen. now it is present no matter what size of screen you are on.

Comment: For me, red colour is present only on smaller screen with your code.

Comment: *"now it is present no matter what size of screen you are on"* - no it isn't with bootstrap 3 or 4 https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/aWQPwG replicate the issue for us.

Comment: @makshh can you show me how you do it?

Comment: The same as @MichaelCoker codepen.

Comment: that from  @MichaelCoker codepen is not working at all on smaller screen!

Comment: @MichaelCoker it should be `min-width` not `max`.

Comment: @teelou *"it should be min-width not max"* it's the code from your post. If that's wrong, update your post.

Comment: @MichaelCoker sorry I updated it and I am on "bootstrap": "^3.3.7", "foundation-sites": "^6.3.0-rc1"

Comment: @teelou it works fine https://media.giphy.com/media/3o7bu2XLHE2AZaJoJy/giphy.gif

Comment: you're saying the red border should only be visible on a small screen? then your media query is wrong. "min-width: 320px" means it will target all viewports > 320px. If you only want the border on a small screen, "max-width: 320px" is what you should be using. And what do you mean by "small screen" exactly?

Comment: @MichaelCoker then you should see the red box on smaller screen but i can't see the red box when  i am the smaller screen.

Comment: well, like my codepen and the animated gif I posted demonstrate, it works on small screens if you use "max-width: 320px" meaning "all devices with a viewport <= 320px". If it isn't working for you, it's your responsibility to provide us the code that reproduces your issue.

Comment: @MichaelCoker it does not work on my website with max-width...

Comment: @teelou *it's your responsibility to provide us the code that reproduces your issue*. If the code you provided works here but not on your website, all we can do is guess as to what's wrong and that isn't productive for any of us.

Comment: @MichaelCoker got it working now after changing it to max-width

Answer (score 0):

This is my error:

```
/* Small Devices, Tablets */
@media only screen and (min-width : 320px),
@media only screen and (min-width : 480px),
@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {
    .button-home {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
}
```

Now works with:

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {

    .button-home {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
}
```